# Is it possible to generate ahead-of-time QML cache in Qt 5.9 Non-comercial?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded, qml

As it is possible to pre-compile or generate ahead-of-time QML cache in commercial QT 5.9. Is there any way for the same in non-commercial verstion. Purpose for this is to improve the performance of QT app working on raspberry pi in terms of compilation or to get warm start always instead of cold start?

Comment: AFAIK, QML files are automatically compiled the first time you run Qt 5.9 application.

Comment: See [QML Caching for Deployment (Preview)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#qml-caching-for-deployment-preview)

Comment: Not in 5.9 IIRC

Comment: According to git log qmlcache.prf was added in 5.9. Here's the same link for Qt 5.9: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtquick-deployment.html#qml-caching-for-deployment-preview

Comment: What kind of RPI? Note that neither the JIT or the qmlcachegen can generate ARMv5 instructions, so it won't help RPI1 devices.

Comment: That's RPI B+ v1.2 model